# Switches in listview automatically gets check when scrolled

Tags: android, listview, switchcompat

I know this question is duplicate to this one

[Switches in listview automatically gets check android when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145176/switches-in-listview-automatically-gets-check-android-when-scrolled) but the answer doesen't work for me

I am stuck at same problem when i scroll through listview switch get check automatically.
My logic is set switch to on if data is equal to **'1'** which is retrived from database and its working fine but when i scroll through list all switch get checked.

here is my code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(null==view){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
    }
    final ApplicationInfo data = appList.get(position);
    if(null !=data){
        final SwitchCompat appName = (SwitchCompat)view.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        //Read Data
        dbHelper db = new dbHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database1.rawQuery("select isLocked from apps where package='"+appList.get(position).packageName+"'",null);
        if(cursor !=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.getInt(0) == 1){
                appName.setChecked(true);
            }
        }

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        iconView.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));

        appName.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    //appList.get(position).packageName
                    dbHelper dbHelper = new dbHelper(context);
                    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    database.execSQL("update apps set 'isLocked'=1 where package='"+appList.get(position).packageName+"'");
                }else {
                    dbHelper dbHelper = new dbHelper(context);
                    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    database.execSQL("update apps set 'isLocked'=0 where package='"+appList.get(position).packageName+"'");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ListView`, the items are reused when scrolling. If the checkbox is already checked, it needs to be unchecked before using it.

Use:

```
if(cursor.getInt(0) == 1){
    appName.setChecked(true);
} else {
    appName.setChecked(false);
}
```

in place of

```
if(cursor.getInt(0) == 1){
    appName.setChecked(true);
}
```

Or reset/uncheck the checkbox before performing other tasks:

```
View view = convertView;
if(null==view){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
}

final SwitchCompat appName = (SwitchCompat)view.findViewById(R.id.appName);
appName.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
appName.setChecked(false);

final ApplicationInfo data = appList.get(position);
if(null !=data){
    // your code.
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace `if(null==view)` with `if(true)` ? -- Just for testing, don't use it permanently

Comment: Do you mean it is working after using `if(true)`? If so, don't use it. It is a bad practice, it can be solved in other way.

Comment: tell me another way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173316/discussion-between-rohit-chauhan-and-nabin-bhandari).

Answer (score 0):

Please remove code that assigns/binds data out of `public View getView`

and move it to `public void onBindViewHolder`